# Facebook iFrame app - getting rid of vertical scrollbars?

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, scrollbar, facebook-iframe

I've converted [a Facebook app](http://apps.facebook.com/video-preferans/) from FBML to iFrame (with PHP SDK) and now have vertical scrollbars displayed for the same amount of content I had before (a logo, a flash game and a line with 3 links below). But earlier I didn't have any scrollbars.

If I set the app setting Auto-Resize, then the lower part of content isn't displayed at all - which is bad, the flash game is unplayable then.

I've searched around and all suggested solutions involve Javascript, but I'm actually using PHP SDK. Isn't there a solution for PHP/CSS only?

Below my current code:

```
<?php

require_once('facebook.php');

define('FB_API_ID', 'XXX');
define('FB_AUTH_SECRET', 'XXX');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'  => FB_API_ID,
            'secret' => FB_AUTH_SECRET,
            'cookie' => true,
            ));

if (! $facebook->getSession()) {
    printf('<script type="text/javascript">top.location.href="%s";</script>',
        $facebook->getLoginUrl(
                array('canvas'    => 1,
                      'fbconnect' => 0,
                      #'req_perms' => 'user_location',
        )));
    exit();
} else {
    try {
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');

        $first_name = $me['first_name'];
        $city       = $me['location']['name'];
        $female     = ($me['gender'] == 'male' ? 0 : 1);
        $avatar     = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' . $me['id'] . '/picture?type=large';

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        exit('Facebook error: ' . $e);
    }
}

# print the logo, the flash game and 3 links

?>
```

Also I'm not sure if my PHP-script is supposed to print

```
<html>
<body> 
.....
</body>
</html>
```

? Currently I only print what's inside the body.

And I wonder if it is a good idea to replace **top.location.href=....** in my code by PHP's **header('Location: ....');**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use the Asynchronous method, it's recommended that you put as much of FB code within it. Something like the below should work:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
    FB.Canvas.setSize();
};

function sizeChangeCallback() {
    FB.Canvas.setSize();
}
(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
e.src = document.location.protocol +
  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now you will call the `sizeChangeCallback()` function whenever you make a change to the layout (clicking new tab, loading Ajax content...etc).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found [the solution](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.canvas.setsize/):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.Canvas.setSize();
}

function sizeChangeCallback() {
        FB.Canvas.setSize();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
......

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
        appId  : '<?php print(FB_API_ID); ?>',
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        xfbml  : true
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and set **IFrame Size** to **Auto-resize** in the settings tab.

And **header('Location: ' . $url);** won't work for whatever reason.

Comment: 1) `header` won't work because you are working inside an iframe 2) you should wrap **all** FB related JS functions inside the `window.fbAsyncInit` method (I mean here the `FB.init`)

Comment: Unfortunately, not: I've tried your fbAsyncInit-suggestion (coming from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/  ?) and it does not work with Google Chrome: the iframe content is just cut off at the bottom.

Comment: +1 for your persistency, I will try your suggestion later, thank you

Comment: And I also wonder, if the document.getElementById() that you suggest is a good choice for all browsers. Google Chrome prints a warning about it in the console. Maybe <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"> is on a safer side?

Comment: A lot of browsers will complain about various things, but I suppose it's safe to use it like so and it would assure that the resize function will actually execute when the JS library is loaded. If this works for you tell me to add it as a solution

Comment: FB.Canvas.SetAutoResize, why did you put setSize only?

Comment: @dragonjet, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoResize/ says, FB.Canvas.SetAutoResize is for cases, when content changes over time - and I only have a static logo pic, static flash game and 3 HTML-links. So I don't think I need it, seems to work ok without.

Comment: @ifaour, tried your solution and it seems to work too - please post it as solution and you'll get the "candy" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just put together a quite extensive tutorial on my blog, also using the PHP-SDK. Besides getting rid of those scrollbars I also show how to create a Fan-Gate and a simple Share-Button. I hope I can help some of you guys with that:

http://net-bites.de/facebook/tutorial-how-to-create-facebook-iframe-pages-for-timeline-width-810px-with-fan-gate-and-share-button/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

My Sollution works every time! Make your body overflow hidden then before  add this.

```
<div id="fb-root" class="fb_reset"><script async="" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
           FB.init({appId: '293887700673244', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true});
           window.setTimeout(function() {
               FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(); }, 250);
       };

       (function() { var e = document.createElement('script');
           e.async = true;
           e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
           document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e); }());
   </script>
```