# Pure JavaScript function similar to jQuery.offset()?

Tags: javascript, iframe, social-networking

In a small [iframe-application](http://ok.ru/games/preferans) at the Russian social network Ok.ru I use the following call to resize the iframe:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script src="http://api.odnoklassniki.ru/js/fapi.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
FAPI.init("http://api.odnoklassniki.ru/", "XXX_YYY",
function() {
        alert("clientHeight " + document.getElementById("fb-root").clientHeight);
        alert("offsetHeight " + document.getElementById("fb-root").offsetHeight);
        FAPI.UI.setWindowSize(720, 1200);
}, function(error){
        alert("API initialization failed");
});
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

i.e. the iframe-height is currently hardcoded to **1200**.

It works okay, but I'd like to use the height/position of **#fb-root** element instead.

Does anybody please have an idea, which JavaScript or CSS function could be used here - if I don't want to include [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/offset/) just for one **$(#fb-root).offset()** call?

I've also looked at their library http://api.odnoklassniki.ru//js/fapi.js but it doesn't include such function.

**UPDATE**

I've added two alert-calls to my source code above, but they only print

```
clientHeight 0
offsetHeight 0
```

**UPDATE**

The following code seem to work well for my iframe-app now in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox, regardless of how many 
s do I add for testing it. But with Internet Explorer it fails to resize the window and alert shows top=1107 instead of top=1157 in Google Chrome, thus the html table at the bottom is cut off:

[image: preferans]

```
... here my flash game + html table with players ...
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://api.odnoklassniki.ru/js/fapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
FAPI.init("http://api.odnoklassniki.ru/", "XXX_YYY",
function() {
        var top = findTop(document.getElementById("fb-root"));
        FAPI.UI.setWindowSize(720, Math.max(top, 1200));
}, function(error){
        alert("API initialization failed");
});
function findTop(obj) {
        if(!obj) return 0;
        return obj.offsetTop + findTop(obj.offsetParent);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't post urls that 1.) require registration 2.) are in russian... :)) It's rather useless.

Comment: What about Facebook questions? There is a lot of them here and they require registration.

Comment: But everybody is on FB, so it doesn't really require you to register if you wanna help. And it's certainly not in russian(only). :)

Comment: It does not matter, if it is a Russian, Hungarian or US social network. I was trying to solve a JavaScript/iframe problem and have supplied enough information at the beginning and later. If you check my other questions here at Stackoverflow, you will see, that I always do that (provide enough information and test cases and responding to every comment when asking anything).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quirksmode has a JavaScript tutorial/function that shows how to find the coordinates of an element [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html)

Once you have its coordinates, you can use the offsetHeight property of the iframe to read its height.

Comment: This seems like a solid solution, because it traverses the DOM from the element through all its containers, which should work even if the element in question has zero height - as long as some of the containers have height. Any idea explanation why it was voted down?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've updated my question with working code. Any ideas why it fails for MSIE?

Comment: I would try calling findTop in the window.load event and possibly in a separate button call to see if it gives different information. I've heard before that IE may give incorrect information for the offset properties if its still loading the dom. Another thing to try would be to set position:relative for the "fb-root" div and see if that gives you a different answer. If you do this, also check the margin and padding of the html element.

Answer (score 27):

Looking at the [code in jquery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/d0ce00cdfa680f1f0c38460bc51ea14079ae8b07/src/offset.js#L87), the offset is calculated like this:

```js
function getOffset(element)
{
    if (!element.getClientRects().length)
    {
      return { top: 0, left: 0 };
    }

    let rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    let win = element.ownerDocument.defaultView;
    return (
    {
      top: rect.top + win.pageYOffset,
      left: rect.left + win.pageXOffset
    });   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, A Lot. It saves My Lot's of time

Answer (score 1):

If `document.getElementById("fb-root").clientHeight` returns 0, it certainly means that your "fb-root" div is either not displayed or still empty.

I have had a look at fapi.js, and it seems that calling the FAPI.init function creates a span which id is "FAPI_Flash_wrap", appends it to the body of the document, then embeds a flash object with id "FAPI_Flash" in this span.

So I would try retrieving an element with id "FAPI_Flash_wrap" or "FAPI_Flash" instead of "fb-root":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
FAPI.init("http://api.odnoklassniki.ru/", "XXX_YYY",
function() {
    alert("Height = " + document.getElementById("FAPI_Flash_wrap").offsetHeight);
    alert("Width = " + document.getElementById("FAPI_Flash_wrap").offsetWidth);
    FAPI.UI.setWindowSize(720, 1200);
}, function(error){alert("API initialization failed");}
);
</script>
```

I hope this works!

If it's the case, then just use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
FAPI.init("http://api.odnoklassniki.ru/", "XXX_YYY",
function() {
    var height = document.getElementById("FAPI_Flash_wrap").offsetHeight;
    var width = document.getElementById("FAPI_Flash_wrap").offsetWidth;
    FAPI.UI.setWindowSize(width, height);
}, function(error){alert("API initialization failed");}
);
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but alerts do not appear at all and the page is not resized. In the Firebug console I see many warnings but no related error. When I put back my original code with hardcoded height - then it suddenly works ok.

Comment: Hmm, strange. If you try "alert(document.getElementById(someID));" in the Firebug command line, it will necessarily popup either "[object someInterfaceName]" or "null", so you can check if an element with id "someID" exists at this moment. If neither "FAPI_Flash_wrap" nor "FAPI_Flash" exists, maybe the full HTML of the page after successfully loading the game would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use **offsetHeight** or **clientHeight** to get div's height:

```
document.getElementById("fb-root").offsetHeight // including border
document.getElementById("fb-root").clientHeight // excluding border
```

Use **offsetLeft** and **offsetTop** to get div's position relative to its **offsetParent**. **offsetParent** is its first parent box which position style is fixed, relative or absolute.

Comment: Thank you, but does getElementById() wotrk with all main browsers?

Comment: YES. Almost all browsers supported **getElementById**. [see this link](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html)

Comment: Unfortunately both offsetHeight and clientHeight are printed as 0 for some reason - please see my updated question

Comment: Can you paste the content of #fb-root completely? Or give me the link of your test page that I can access.

Comment: The address is http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/game/preferans (I'm sorry - it is at the Russian Facebook-clone). When I alert("XXX " + document.getElementById("fb-root").clientHeight); it prints "XXX 0". The <div id="fb-root"></div> is empty. Above it is my Flash game. I've used an empty div, because that is how it is usually done for the real Facebook: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928724/facebook-iframe-app-getting-rid-of-vertical-scrollbars

Comment: Are you sure #fb-root already has content when you are getting its height? If you use safari or chrome(or use FireBug in Firefox), you can run **document.getElementById("fb-root").offsetHeight** in the console of Developer Tool to check if it works. Good luck.

Comment: fb-root has no content in it, but when I put xxx into it: <div id="fb-root">xxx</div> - then nothing changes. The Firebug console prints: [06:44:17.768] TypeError: document.getElementById("fb-root") is null