# Convert jQuery offset() to pure JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got an application form with multiple steps and several fields using HTML and jQuery. I'm using the jQuery Validator plugin, and am able to scroll a user to an invalid field by getting the element, and getting the `offset()` position.

```js
$(validator.errorList[0].element).offset().top
```

I'm trying to convert this into compatible javascript using the suggestion from http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ to essentially get the element using:

```js
var myInvalidField = validator.errorList[0].element;
var rect = myInvalidField.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(rect.top);
```

However, they both seem to return different values, my my example:

using the jQuery `offset()` I get a value returned as **274**, and using the pure JS approach **-285**. I'm not sure what's wrong with the calculation.

How can I get my values to match the returned value from `offset()`

Comment: Possible duplicate : [Pure JavaScript function similar to jQuery.offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139720/pure-javascript-function-similar-to-jquery-offset)

Comment: From your linked page (specifically http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#offset): `top: rect.top + document.body.scrollTop,`  you've missed the bit that compensates for the body (of course, that might be 0...)

Comment: I answered your question, [in the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60083373/204723)